# A bug in code about write a class that is same array of pointer?

Tags: c++

Hello to all i have below code
in `PointArray.h`

```
#ifndef POINTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define POINTARRAY_H_INCLUDED

template <typename T>
class PointArray
{
private:
    int nSize;
    T *array[];
public:
    PointArray();
    PointArray(const T *points[],const int size);
    PointArray(const PointArray &pv);
    ~PointArray();
    int * get(const int position);//is same to array[position]
    const int * get(const int position) const;//is same to array[position]
    const int getSize() const;//get size of array
};

#endif // POINTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
```

in `PointArray.cpp`

```
#include "PointArray.h"
#include<iostream>
#include <assert.h>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
PointArray<T>::PointArray(const T *points[],const int size)
{
    nSize=size;
    for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        array[i]=new T;
        *array[i]=*points[i];
    }
}

template<class T>
PointArray<T>::PointArray()
{
    nSize=0;
}

template<class T>
PointArray<T>::PointArray(const PointArray &pv)
{
    nSize=pv.getSize();
    for (int i=0;i<nSize;i++)
    {
        array[i]=new T;
        *array[i]=*(pv.get(i));
    }
}

template<class T>
const int PointArray<T>::getSize() const
{
    return nSize;
}

template<class T>
PointArray<T>::~PointArray()
{
    delete[] array;
    nSize=0;
}

template<class T>
int * PointArray<T>::get(const int position)
{
    assert(position>-1 && position<nSize);
    return array[position];
}

template<class T>
const int * PointArray<T>::get(const int position) const
{
    return array[position];
}
```

in `main.cpp`

```
#include<iostream>
#include "PointArray.h"
#include "PointArray.cpp"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int x=22;
    int y=3;
    const int * a[2]={&x,&y};
    PointArray<int> p;
    PointArray<int> p2(a,2);
    PointArray<int> p3(p2);
    cout << p.getSize() << endl;
    cout << p2.getSize() << endl;
    cout << p3.getSize() << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

above code should print

```
0
2
2
```

but output is

```
9244616
9244600
2
```

and when i run it again `9244616` , `9244600` is changed.
what is problem?

Comment: INitialize the nSize to 0 in constructor

Comment: @Abhijit Kadam  i dont get your sentence

Comment: I though you are not setting nSize but later saw in constructor body. Usually it is initialed in initialization list as against in body hence missed to notice. Strange it behave as if nSize is not set to proper value.

Comment: @MM-BB: there you go.. though I think you need to revisit your memory allocations and members structure

Comment: What is the size of `array` member? Where is it allocated? Your program invokes undefined behavior

Comment: @MM-BB rewrite your example with just the default constructed object, if that is wrong then you need to understand why. Go from there and use a debugger to understand what is actually happening when it is created - step through it...

Comment: @Tadeusz Kopec what( Where is it allocated)?

Comment: @ Caribou i test it by debuger but very dont get any thing

Comment: @MM-BB My mistake - `array` is not allocated. It is only deallocated in destructor (`delete[] array`). Here is one UB you invoke. Another one is accessing `array` elements. How many elements does it have?

Comment: @MM-BB I have all the original OP code (header, cpp and main) in main.cpp and I get 0 0 2 in vs2012, so it is likely that you are invoking undefined behavior somewhere. UB examples in this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/367633/what-are-all-the-common-undefined-behaviour-that-a-c-programmer-should-know-ab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that you are including the cpp file in the main and implementing there, template implementations should be done in the h files.
Your h file should be:

```
 #ifndef POINTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
#define POINTARRAY_H_INCLUDED

template <typename T>
class PointArray
{
private:
    int nSize;
    T *array[];
public:
    PointArray()
    {
        nSize=0;
    }
    PointArray(const T *points[],const int size)
    {
        nSize=size;
        for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            array[i]=new T;
            *array[i]=*points[i];
        }
    }
    PointArray(const PointArray &pv)
    {
        nSize=pv.getSize();
        for (int i=0;i<nSize;i++)
        {
            array[i]=new T;
            *array[i]=*(pv.get(i));
        }
    }
    ~PointArray()
    {
        delete[] array;
        nSize=0;
    }
    int * get(const int position)
    {
        assert(position>-1 && position<nSize);
        return array[position];
    }
    const int * get(const int position) const
    {
        return array[position];
    }
    const int getSize() const { return nSize;}
};

#endif // POINTARRAY_H_INCLUDED
```

Code is still kind of hard and the allocations are bad(notice you get heap assert at the end of the process).. but it worked for me:
0
2
2
is printed...
Cheers.

(Notice that:)

```
delete[] array;
```

is a memory leak, since your object is not an array per say but you try to define pointers to arrays, you should change it to

```
T** array
```

and then at the destructor loop on the array first dimension and then do `delete[] array`

Comment: Could you clarify your answer a bit, what was wrong with the OP exactly? (Then I'll +1)

Comment: @Alon your answer is for better and code write the code but problem exist

Comment: Edited, thought I was clear, @MM-BB did you try putting it in the headers? it worked for me when I ran it

Comment: @Alon unedited code gives me 0 0 2 on vs2012 - it does however emit warnings

Comment: @Caribou yup it is because of the other thing I stated, the T* member[] is a warning, you cannot define it with zero size, it should be T**

Comment: @MM-BB from vs2012 : warning C4200: nonstandard extension used : zero-sized array in struct/union Cannot generate copy-ctor or copy-assignment operator when UDT contains a zero-sized array

Comment: @i ran it again and it work but it print  `12 [sig] PointArray 3424 open_stackdumpfile: Dumping stack trace to PointArray.exe.stackdump`

Comment: There's no difference between `typename` and `class` in template parameters.

Comment: That might be the memory allocations issues Ive stated, in the last section I try to give a clue

Comment: @Alon I haven't downvoted btw

Comment: Doesn't matter, re-editted it to a sentence, it solves the problem @DanHulme thanks for feedback, removed that note

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is

```
T *array[];
```

You define an array of pointers with no elements. Then you try to access its (nonexistent) elements which results in undefined behavior.

Another undefined behavior is in destructor

```
delete[] array;
```

You should only `delete[]` things that were `new[]`-ed. `array` wasn't. Instead you should loop over all `array` elements (if there were any) and delete each of them.

The best solution is to use `std::vector` instead of array. If you insist on using array, change `T* array[]` to `T **array`, in constructor allocate memory for it

```
array = new T*[size];
```

and in destructor delete all array elements before deleting array itself.